# Explain plan in gremlin Tinkerpop3 (DSE graph)

Tags: datastax-enterprise, gremlin, tinkerpop3, datastax-enterprise-graph

I have written one query which is taking longer than expected time.

```
g.V().hasLabel('Person').has('name','Person1').out('BELONGS').in('HAS').dedup().as('x').in('HAS').filter(__.in('HAS').has('name','App1')).store('y').select('x').dedup().in('HAS').hasLabel('Org').repeat(out()).until(outE().hasLabel('IS')).store('a').cap('y').unfold().in('HAS').hasLabel('Class').repeat(inE('IS').dedup().otherV()).until(inE('HAS')).where(within('a'))
```

Can we do an explain plan to look out what is making this query slower?

Regards

Varun Tahin

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have several tools at your disposal when picking apart a Gremlin traversal. You can uses the [explain()](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#explain-step) step and/or the [profile()](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#profile-step) step. The `explain()` step will show how the traversal is composed and modified by Traversal Strategies which optimize its execution. The `profile()` step will provide statistics on traversal execution itself.

I would also call the Gremlin Console itself a "tool". Debugging Gremlin sometimes takes me down a path of executing smaller chunks of a traversal so that I can determine what it is returning at any given point in the list of steps. The Gremlin Console, as it is a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop), provides the ability to get immediate feedback on code execution, thus getting you out of the longer development cycle of your IDE.